# OS X XMPP logout Chat Application using xcode 6.4

Tags: macos, xmpp, logout

I am developing chat application in os x with XMPP framework, where there is main chat viewcontroller with chat view but when user clicks logout button i navigate user to login viewcontroller by calling offline method,xmpp disconnect method and self window close. After this during re-login xmpp connection is not happening.

code used :

```
-(void)logout
{
    [self goOffline];
    [self xmppStreamDidDisconnect:xmppStream withError:nil];

    ViewController *bcktologin =[self.storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    [self presentViewControllerAsModalWindow:bcktologin];
    [self dismissViewController:self];
    [self.view.window close];

}
```

so after this:

1. My chat controller keeps running behind, menu created in it is no removed.
2. No connection to XMPP after re-login

Please guide.

Comment: You do not have to call   [self xmppStreamDidDisconnect:xmppStream withError:nil];. Instead call [_xmppStream disconnect]; and then when you login back you need to set up steam and call [_xmppStream connect];

Comment: But my menu items added to main menu  from chat view are not removing when logged out and while login back i have used xmppstream connect but still no connecting

Comment: You can post this query in git forum.By the way which library u using for xmpp?